# Listing filenames with special characters

Tags: zsh, ls, unicode, oh-my-zsh

I have a `zsh` shell (with oh-my-zsh default config). Why I `ls` filenames with special characters, they are printed as:

```
''$'\316\262''=0.35-L=32-m=10.jld2'
```

This should be:

```
β=0.35-L=32-m=10.jld2
```

but the `β` seems to throw-off `ls`. Is there a way to fix this?

**UPDATE:** As suggested in the comments here is output of my `locale`:

```
(base) ➜ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

There seems to be an error there. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your current locale (the output from `locale`)? It seems to work on my system, provided I'm using an UTF-8 capable locale.

Comment: @Kusalananda I added my `locale` output. It seems I might have some misconfiguration, any suggestions on how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, setting

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

in my `.zshrc` file solved the issue!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/599808/cannot-set-lc-ctype-to-default-locale-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @kusalananda, the issue might be your locale. What are the values of your `LC_*` variables (e.g `LC_ALL`)?

I managed to reproduce the issue by setting `LC_ALL=C`.

To change your locale you may use the `localectl` command:

1. `localectl list-locales`
2. `localectl set-locale`

Or set an environment variable in your `.zshrc`:

`LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`